# I have msg.sender issue

Tags: erc-20

Lets suppose here are user A and smartcontract B and C(sort of regular dapp). A has no token but little ETH for gas, but B has enough tokens(Erc20).

1. A send TX to B
2. B send call to C
3. C receive tokens in B and give service to A. 
   In addition, C check balance of msg.sender while execution.

In this case, which one should I use delegatecall or just call to make this logic feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If B wants to send the tokens to C he must call the original token contract's `transfer` function to issue the send. After that transfer has succeeded (it will be done synchronously within the same transaction) B can send some dummy message to C to notify him of the transfer - otherwise C will not know that he has received tokens since it's impossible for contracts to be notified of token transfers.

B can simply call some function in C such as `iHaveSentYouTokens` and C can then verify his token balance from the same token contract and perform the service for A.

Comment: Is it delegatecall? or just call?

Comment: Just a normal function call

Comment: Hi @Lauri, is there any requirement for dapp to be adopted as contract C in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. If you mean whether C has to be a contract then yes, it has to be a contract, otherwise it can't perform anything automatically.

Comment: C is contract. I am asking can any contract be adopted as contract C. or, is there any requirement here.

Comment: Is C a special case or regular case?

Comment: If C needs to give some service for A, it has to be a special contract. Furthermore, any contract can hold tokens but they can't use them unless they have functionality written for it.

Comment: so you mean any contract that has function which gives service to buyer can be interacted with contract B in this case?

Comment: B only sends tokens to C and that has no requirements - you can send tokens wherever you want without considering what is at the other end. But if C wants to *use* those tokens in some way he needs special functionality for it.

Comment: Let me explain another example. Here are smartcontract A and B

B has BuyService function. User need to call this function to get service. A has token(erc20) enough. If user call A without tokens, then A call B and pay tokens on behalf of user. B receive tokens from A and give service to user. B is very regular and simple standard contract.

Can contract A work? If so, can any contract be interacted with A?

Comment: Yes, you can make such a contract as A. But the problem you will face is that there is no such thing as "call a contract with tokens". A contract has no way of knowing when it receives tokens as tokens are the amount of tokens each address owns are only registered inside the token contract.. If you have further questions please post a new question - comments section is not a good place for extended discussions